# Server-Sent Events not working on a certain server

Tags: javascript, apache, server-sent-events

Based on [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) article:

> SSEs are sent over traditional HTTP. That means they do not require a special protocol or server implementation to get working.

I've used the solution mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events.

Original Code: https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/tree/master/server-sent-events

**I have two servers with similar configurations. But on one of the script is not working.** A connection is not established and is treated as a normal HTTP Request rather than event stream. So after max_execution_time return 500 Internal Server Error instead of sending proper events.

- Working server: http://test.frontlabs.pl/server-sent-events/
- Not working server: http://www.bitreporter.com/server-sent-events/

Can you help out how to debug it? How to pinpoint the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution to my problem. I changed PHP version from FastCGI to CGI and it started working.

But why - I have no idea :(